# how to test vue component passing method

Tags: unit-testing, vue.js, vue-component

I have a Vue component `modal` which has `onClose` prop passed by its parent. When click `ok` button, the `onClose` method will be triggered. The code is as below:

```js
Vue.component('modal', {
  template: '#modal-template',
  props: {
    onClose: {
      type: Function
    }
  },
  methods: {
    ok() {
      this.onClose();
    }
  }
})

// start app
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  methods: {
    close() {
     alert('close')
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://npmcdn.com/vue@1.0.26/dist/vue.min.js"></script>

<script type="x/template" id="modal-template">
  <div class="modal-mask">
    <button @click='ok()'> OK </button>
  </div>
</script>

<div id="app">
  <modal :on-close="close" ></modal>
</div>
```

I think the unit test for `modal` component should define `spy` on `close` method, so the test should be as below:

```
let vm = new Vue({
  template: '<div><modal v-ref:test-component :on-close="close"></modal></div>',
  methods: {
    close: sinon.spy()
  },
  components: { ConfirmModal }
}).$mount()
const modal = vm.$refs.testComponent
modal.ok()
expect(vm.close).have.been.called()
```

The test failed with error: **`TypeError: [Function] is not a spy or a call to a spy!`**

Answer (score 0):

Here is an excerpt from the unit tests:

```
it('methods', function () {
  var spy = jasmine.createSpy()
  var vm = new Vue({
    el: el,
    template: '<a v-on:click="test"></a>',
    data: {a: 1},
    methods: {
      test: spy
    }
  })
  var a = el.firstChild
  trigger(a, 'click')
  expect(spy.calls.count()).toBe(1)
  vm.$destroy()
  trigger(a, 'click')
  expect(spy.calls.count()).toBe(1)
})
```